# Search shows result after I remove Text from EditText

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to fetch data from firestore. When I type in the editText the `RecyclerView` doesn't show results. but when I remove the text from

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

  mStore.collection("Featured").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", newText).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {@Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
          Items f1 = doc.toObject(Items.class);
          mItemList.add(f1);
          mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Log.d("SearchItem", f1.getName());
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return true;
}
```

Comment: other than the fact that you're _using_ android studio to develop your app, you're not asking about a feature of the IDE, right ?

Comment: yes right!  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You don't call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside loop . move it out of Loop .

Comment: are you able to get the log inside loop?

Comment: yes I am getting the log but when I remove the text from EditText. and also I tried to move ```mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()``` out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I just have to convert the string into lower case with `toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`. Locale is helpful when we are doing case operations and URL related tasks. You can learn more about locale from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html .

```
mItemList.clear();
                mStore.collection("Featured").orderBy("name").whereLessThanOrEqualTo("name", newText.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)).get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                                        Items f1 = doc.toObject(Items.class);
                                        mItemList.add(f1);
                                        Log.d("SearchItem", f1.getName());
                                    }
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```